# In a tableselect form element with '#js_select' => FALSE, how can I re-use the column header for a label?

Tags: 7, forms

I have a pretty ordinary tableselect element that looks like so

```
$form['registration_table'] = array(
    '#title'=>"Register",
    '#type' => 'tableselect',
    '#header' => $header,
    '#options' => $enrollment_options,
    '#js_select' => FALSE,
    '#multiple' => TRUE,
);
```

What I would like is to be able to use the empty space which is reserved for the "select all" checkbox for a text label. I would like to indicate by the label what action the checkboxes represent. In this case they represent selecting a course to register for so I would like to add the label "Register" there. Any advice on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

For doing this you have to change the "theme_tableselect" core code. See this [documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/theme_tableselect/7) code part. If you do not set "select all" then the header is assigned to null